# Cannot print image full path because of django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation

Tags: django, static, media

I want to print / get the full path of an ImageField in django

```
    photos = Photo.objects.all()
    for photo in photos:
        print(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + photo.image.path)
        break
```

Bu I get this:

```
    print(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + photo.image.file)
  File "/home/juan/Desktop/juan/dev/yas/yas_django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 43, in _get_file
    self._file = self.storage.open(self.name, 'rb')
  File "/home/juan/Desktop/juan/dev/yas/yas_django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 36, in open
    return self._open(name, mode)
  File "/home/juan/Desktop/juan/dev/yas/yas_django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 224, in _open
    return File(open(self.path(name), mode))
  File "/home/juan/Desktop/juan/dev/yas/yas_django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 323, in path
    return safe_join(self.location, name)
  File "/home/juan/Desktop/juan/dev/yas/yas_django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/_os.py", line 46, in safe_join
    'component ({})'.format(final_path, base_path))
django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation: The joined path (/images/photos/2013/3/image_1) is located outside of the base path component (/home/juan/Desktop/juan/dev/yas/yas_django/media)
```

What is going on here? This is in my settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

The same happens if I print image.url or image.file. What I want to get is the full path to the image in order to open it with a third party lib.

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.2